# Limits to inlining function wrappers in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, inlining

My question concerns the application of inline optimisations on function wrappers in C++, consider the following code, the WorkerStructure object is initialised with a function wrapper that encapsulates some chunk of functionality. The function wrapper is then used when the WorkerStructure::doSomeWork method is invoked.

Will the functionality encapsulated by the workerFunction object be inlined when applied on the WorkerStructure::doSomeWork method?, obviously if the functionality is defined in some other translation unit, the workerFunction object only encapsulates a function pointer, **are there any other circumstances where inlining will not be possible?**

When a lambda function defined in a different translation unit is passed via the function wrapper, is it effectively equivalent to passing a function pointer?

```
struct WorkerStructure
{
    WorkerStructure(std::function <bool(float)> &f):workerFunction(f) {}

    void doSomeWork(float inputValue)
    {
        if(workerFunction(inputValue))
        {
            //do some conditional operation
        }
    }
    std::function <bool(float)> workerFunction ;
};
```

Comment: It strongly depends upon the compiler and the optimization flags. FYI recent GCC (i.e. 4.7) has a link-time optimization ability (with compiling **and** *linking* with `gcc -flto -O2`)

Comment: Cool!, did not know about flto, I'm experimenting a lot with lambda functions, I really like the flexibilty that they give me but I'm loathe to accept any performance degredation, hence the question.

Comment: I have recently switched large parts of my code to using lambdas in gcc 4.7.0 without experiencing a performance hit (I essentially replaced `for()` loops over some self-brewed iterator-like objects to access complicated data structures with `for_each_obj(lambda)`, where the `for_each_obj` template is provided by the data structure, allowing better optimization of the loop logic).

Comment: But, using lambdas does, of course, *not* imply using `std::function`. the latter may well result in performance hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polymorphic nature of `std::function` inherently makes it *very very* difficult to actually inline the call. Since a `std::function` can story any callable entity; how would you write the inlining code?

It's somewhat like inlining virtual functions which are called through the base pointer with no other information available (aka no assignment from derived to base pointer prior to the invokation, which the compiler might use to enable inlining).

Most of the time, `std::function` is implemented with a `void*` pointer and a function pointer to a specialization of a templated function, that does the actual invokation and casting and stuff. There are of course variants that use virtual functions to do this, and it's clearer with them why it's astonishingly hard. Even link-time opimization won't be able to do anything, since it doesn't matter, you already have all the information you can get at the call site (which isn't much).

Here's a *very* crude version of `std::function` using the pointer to template function version, dealing only with the store and call aspect (leaving out memory management, copying, moving, resetting, space optimization etc.):

```
template<class Sig>
class function;

template<class R, class... Args>
class function<R(Args...)>{
  typedef R (*call_type)(void*, Args...);
  void* _obj;
  call_type _caller;

public:
  template<class F>
  function(F f)
    : _obj(new F(f))
    , _caller([](void* p, Args... args){ return (*static_cast<F*>(p))(args...); })
  {}

  R operator()(Args... args) const{
    return _caller(_obj, args...);
  }
};
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/d2d630bed65db7ea98c215fb8fa9acda) I think it'd be very hard to check what is actually inside of `_obj` and `_caller` and the point where the `function` is invoked.

Just for reference, [here's the version with virtual functions](http://liveworkspace.org/code/06c147b9d6cb882ec4cd7feade28e426).

Comment: Happily it seems that by passing the lambda as a template parameter, inlining is appiled correctly, I verified this by eyeballing the optimised disassembled object code.

Comment: @Gearoid: Oh, that's cool then. :) I guess it only works if you call the `std::function` in the same scope that you stored something in it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Amusingly, I asked about inlining of virtual functions in Clang/LLVM on [the mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-September/024619.html) just today. The dynamic nature of `std::function` makes it essentially a virtual call, because `virtual` calls are not much more than pointer to functions.

Using LLVM as an example, let us play with the following program:

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef void (*Function)();

void donothing() {}
void print() { printf("Hello World!"); }

Function get(int i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) { return donothing; }
    return print;
}

int main() {
    Function f = get(0);
    f();
}
```

The main function emitted:

```
define i32 @main() uwtable readnone {
  ret i32 0
}
```

Therefore, the compiler has the ability to understand which function gets selected (with a combination of inlining and constant propagation), and did inline the call.

Unfortunately, I demonstrated in my e-mail that passing though virtual tables this does not work (the optimizer somehow lost information and was not able to inline the call). So while it is perfectly possible that inlining does work through `std::function`, it may very well depend not only on the compiler but also on the particular implementation of `std::function` that you happen to be using. I am afraid that you will need experimenting with your application.